# How do I write inline xaml for a MultiBinding converter?

Tags: c#, xaml, mvvm, converters, multibinding

How do I include the second binding?  Where do the brackets and commas go?

There are five thousand examples that show how to do it in xml but nothing about how this should appear inline.

NOT THIS

```
<TextBlock>
    <TextBlock.Text>
        <MultiBinding StringFormat="{}{0:F1}{1:F1}">
            <Binding Path="A" />
            <Binding Path="B" />
        </MultiBinding>
    </TextBlock.Text>
</TextBlock>
```

THIS

```
<StackPanel Grid.Column="0"
            Orientation="Vertical"
            HorizontalAlignment="Left"
            Visibility="{MultiBinding Converter={StaticResource multi_bool_vis_conv},                                                                                        
            Bindings={Binding LabelFormat.HasLotMaskShiftCode}}">
```

I need to pass a second binding *LabelFormat.HasSomeOtherCode*.  How do I include that second binding?

Comment: Have you looked at converter parameters?

Comment: Yes.  But I don't think I would need a Multibound converter if I was just passing a single object and a parameter.  Are you suggesting that passing a parameter instead of a  second binding is the way to do this?

Comment: What you call "inline" actually would require markup extensions for MultiBinding. I'm not aware of any markup extensions of that kind. Can you explain more precisely what exactly you want to achieve? Maybe there is another way.

Comment: @ewerspej - is there better terminology than *in-line*?  I have to two boolean properties, instead of one, that I want to pass to my converter.  My converter then returns true if all bindings are true or the converter returns false if any are false.  All I need to know how do is pass the second binding in the structure above.  Nothing more.  It's difficult to believe that the second binding cannot be passed without extensions.

Comment: @EllieK I think that Scott Solmer just gave you the answer for that.

Comment: I'm referring to his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/75378931/4308455). There is no such markup extension. You need to do it the way that Scott shows in his answer, AFAIK.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `multi_bool_vis_conv` implements the interface `IMultiValueConverter` and you handle the different parameters by indexing off of the value array, the binding should look like this:

```XML
<MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
    <Binding Path="YourProperty1"/>
    <Binding Path="YourProperty2"/>
</MultiBinding>
```

I assume you want this on one line (*"in-line"*) because you want to set the binding on the StackPanel's Visiblity property and your not sure how to do that in a multi-line way...

You can break it out like this:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Visibility>                            
        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource YourConverter}">
            <Binding Path="YourProperty1" />
            <Binding Path="YourProperty2" />
        </MultiBinding>                            
    </StackPanel.Visibility>
</StackPanel>
```

---

The only other way I can see to do what you want is to roll your own StackPanel and include dependency properties for each of the bindings you want. You can then bind each of those on their own line and forgo a binding on the Visibility property all-together, instead opting to control the visibility in the code-behind of your custom control.

Comment: Thanks, but I already have pages and pages of xaml written the other way.  I can't switch the style just for this item.  I need it **IN LINE**,  like it is in my example.  As I mentioned in my OP there are 5,001 examples of the code above.  It's not what I need.

Comment: I am trying to understand why you need this on one line. It is because your existing code (pages and pages of XAML) all use single property "in-line" bindings, and so you don't want to use a multi-line multi-binding? It doesn't sound like a very strong argument to me, because this is different... It is a multi-binding!

Comment: Strictly cosmetic, Scott.  However, I did get your suggestion to work.  It solved the issue and allowed me to move on.  Thanks for your help.